# How to prevent Axis Line from moving in High Charts JS Visualization?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, visualization

I was wondering if there was a **setting configuration** or a way to fix the vertical Y-axis (.highcharts-axis-line) to prevent it from shifting or moving to the right every time I collapse and expand data in the hierarchy of the Gantt chart. I'm using High Charts JS: https://www.highcharts.com/gantt/demo

[image]

In this animated gif below, see what happens to the vertical right line in the middle every time you click on a dropdown arrow.

[image: Gantt chart animated gif Y Axis]

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('hcContainer', {

    title: {
      text: 'Title'
    },

    yAxis: {
      uniqueNames: true
    },

    navigator: {
      enabled: true,
      liveRedraw: false,
      series: {
        type: 'gantt',
        pointPlacement: 0.5,
        pointPadding: 0.25
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        reversed: true,
        categories: []
      }
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true,
      selected: 0
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Level 1',
      data: //rows
      rows
    }]
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @CodeTraveler, You can try to set `width` property for the labels, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ao50Lxw8/ If that doesn't help, please provide me with some minimal live example of your case.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you so much for sharing this link! I'm going to try what you advise.

Comment: It didn't work, but it was worth a shot.

Comment: Could you provide me with a live example of the problem?

Comment: Thank you for caring @ppotaczek! It's kind of complicated because I'm using real PostgreSQL data and queries in Django views to create an Endpoint to display the data in the JS. I can try to create fake or dummy data to show you how the JS is rendering the visualization.

Comment: Yes, it would be best. The most important thing is to show the problem.